# How change urls dynamically based on chosen language prefix

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 2 languages in Django project. Base is site/pl/ and 2nd is site/en.
There are also 2 buttons in header.html to switch language (add prefix to url). String translation works fine. My problems are:
1. When I switch(click button) between languages I want to load home page because right know it works only when I am at home page - so if I move to any subpage and click to language button it reload same page (not home). 
2. When I switch between languages I want to change also subpages urls to right names.

I try some weird way to made this:

```
        <li><a href="{{baseurl}}">PL</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{en_url}}">EN</a></li>
```

and then in views:

```py
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    baseurl = '/'
    en_url = baseurl + 'en'
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'baseurl': baseurl, 'en_url': en_url})
```

But I assume it's bad.

Here my code:

views.py

```py
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def about(request, *arg, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def offer(request, *arg, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'offer.html')

def contact(request, *arg, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

app urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('o-nas', views.about, name='about'),
    path('oferta', views.offer, name='offer'),
    path('kontakt', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

in header.html

```html
            <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">PL</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">EN</a></li>
```

project urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an url. I would do something like this.

views

```
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
return render(request, 'home.html')

def index_EN(request, *args, **kwargs):
return render(request, 'home_en.html')
```

Dont forget to create a 'home_en.html' template.
Then in urls add:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('en/', views.index_EN, name='index_en'),
```

and then in the template you can use:

```
   <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">PL</a></li>
   <li><a href="{% url 'index_en' %}">EN</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was thinking about that solution but I thought that it's is possible to do it without creating all templates in 2nd language. Because I translate page using django build-in translation {% trans %} tag, so all string are in .po file. Maybe there is any other way?

Comment: Didn't really use the build-in translation. But if you want, i think you need to change you'r view, which you showed at the start. The base url and en_url are not the best. Because when you switch to en language, and click on the base, its goes to the same page basicly. when you're in the en page - the base is the en page.

Comment: maybe try the base_url = ' ' and the en_url = '/en'

Comment: I am trying with you version and when i switch to 2nd language it's ok: site/en/  but when i click back to PL language button it's redirect to home page but url is still site/en - should be site/pl .Also string are not switching to 2nd language.

Comment: what if you changed you're url to path('pl/', views.index, name='index') and then baseurl='/pl' and en_url='/en'

Comment: Error: "Page not found"

Comment: Just go to /pl like in the url instead of ' '

Comment: Now only pl version is working and site/en/ not found: http://prntscr.com/p4aqcu. Mayby problem is prefix_default_language in project urls.py

Comment: And when I'am at any subpage and click to language button only reload current subpage.